# Why do we use "would" in "My dog wouldn't let us catch him" for a past event that happened only once?

Tags: past-tense, would

Look at this sentence, please

> My dog didn't let us catch him

I do understand that sentence but some people would say it like that

> My dog wouldn't let us catch him

Why is that? Why do we use would here? It's something what happens only once and in the past. Please, provide some explanation.

Comment: **Would not**  can have the sense of **refused to**. In this context there isn't much of a difference, but compare 'He didn't go for a walk with us' and 'He wouldn't go for a walk with us'.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, and the will one can mean refuse in the present tense. The point is will and would here are not the same tense.  There are no conditionals here or any other meaning for would, prima facie.

Comment: @Lambie - The question asks about _didn't_ and _wouldn't_, not _will_.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I have shown all three as a way of distinguishing meaning. You can't explain the "would" without the "will" example. I also showed "did". I really see  no other way of explaining these. Can you do better??

Comment: What I mean is  that I know we use would the in the past to talk about things which are repetitive and would have when we say about somwthing what could but didn't  happened or about probability but once I heard a guy he's a youtuber and he commented a scene where a mother didn't let a kid to grab a candy. He said a mother wouldn't let him grab a candy . That's what I don't get why not just didn't?

Comment: No, no and no. would can just be the past tense of will. No repetition: My dog would not let us catch him when he ran off. One time. I explained it in my answer. Please read it.

Comment: So, what the difference in meaning between wouldn't let and didn't let?

Comment: As I told you in my original comment, **did not** simply states that it didn't happen, **would not** that someone deliberately refused to do something. This has nothing to do with using **would** to mean **habitually did**.

Comment: In your example, "wouldn't" implies that the dog **had no desire** to let itself be caught, while **didn't** does not.    "Wouldn't" has several possible meanings in English. For this particular context, the OED has this definition: "In negative contexts, expressing lack of desire or refusal: to have no desire for, not wish for, not want (often with the implication of refusing or declining something)."

Comment: would not let is like will not let (habitual) but in the past tense: My dog will not let me catch him. Past: would not let me catch him.

Comment: @KateBunting I disagree. My dog will not let me catch him. can be **habitual** and the past would be would not in that case.

Comment: @Lambie - True, it can sometimes mean 'habitually refused'. I was just trying to stop the OP from confusing two different issues.

Answer (score 1):

The function here of "would" is to describe something that happened over a span of time in the past, rather than a one-time event.

While this event was brief --maybe a few minutes, rather than prolonged over years-- it's a long enough span of time to use "would" with this function.

This is in contrast with the similar structure *[ "used to" + base form ]*, which can only be used to describe behaviours or situations far in the past and over a significant period of time.

You may have learned that "would" and "used to" have the same meaning when describing past behaviour, but this is not true. There is a lot of overlap, but this example with the dog is one where the behaviour is repeated enough to use "would", but not over enough time to use "used to".

Comment: Not a span of time. Habitually: My little brother would never eat his vegetables.

Comment: @Lambie ???? "Never" indicates a span of time.

Comment: Yes, not eating vegetables can have happened many separate times without indicating a span of time per se.

Comment: @Lambie What's that got to do with my answer, which is restricted to the context of a dog refusing to be caught during some span of time?

Comment: You said: "The function here of "would" is to describe something that happened over a span of time in the past, rather than a one-time event."  And I am saying it is not necessarily a span of time but rather many separate times in the past.

Comment: @Lambie If you do something repeatedly, you necessarily do it over a span of time. In your example, the event of not eating vegetables is repeated every night at dinner for the span of time of his childhood, say.

Answer (score 0):

The dog evaded your attempts to catch him.   That's what **would** signifies, practically speaking. Your dog "willfully" evaded your attempts to catch him.

Without context, one would not know if your dog was a *frequent* escapee, but that might be a reasonable assumption, lacking context, when one encounters the sentence "My dog would not let me catch him." in isolation. Another reasonable assumption would be that you are describing a single incident. **would** fits either scenario.

> When my dog was a puppy, he was very disobedient and would not let me put a leash on him. He would always run away and would not let me catch him.
>
> Last Friday around lunch-time, my dog escaped and kept running away as I approached him. He would not let me catch him.

Whether it is part of a single incident or multiple incidents is not relevant. **would** works for both scenarios. What is relevant to both scenarios is the canine's "willful" evasion. Willful evasion  involves more than one evasive maneuver or some kind of continuous evasive activity. Similarly, when we say of a frozen fastener that "it will not budge" or "it would not budge" there are either multiple attempts to unfreeze it or an extended exertion of pressure on the tool. That is what justifies the use of "will" (past tense "would") in such contexts: the resistance of the thing to bend to your will, and so there is an implication that it has "a will of its own".

Comment: No, would is not a single incident in that dog was a puppy thing. It specifically would mean more than once.

Comment: @Lambie:  The puppy example was offered as an example of the "more than once" scenario; read the sentence immediately prior, which refers to "either scenario".

Comment: I don't think it is used for a single incident.

Comment: There is no context so there is no way to tell much of anything. Look, the dog will not let me catch him! [right now] Oh boy, yesterday my dog would not let me catch him. Past tense of will. I think the willfulness thing just confuses the issue...

Answer (score -5):

Present tense: My dog **will not let us** catch him.  [when he **runs off**]. **A generality**.
Past tense: My dog **would not let us** catch him.
[**when he ran off yesterday**] [past tense of will: would, a generality in the past]
Past tense: My **dog didn't let us** catch him. [last time we played, for example]

They are just two different sentences.

Here, would can be the past tense of will.

> When to use will or would    The word will is an auxiliary verb (helping
> verb) and a modal verb. **It is commonly used together with other verbs
> to express expectations, determinations, capabilities, and several
> other meanings.** For example:
>
> **My pug will eat anything if you let her.**            The forecast said it will
> rain tomorrow.
> Typically, a snake will shed its skin several times
> during its life.

```
Will is also used with every verb to form the future
```

> tense, as in I will go to the beach tomorrow.
>
> **The word would is the past tense form of will. In general, it is used
> in all the same senses of will to express that something occurred in
> the past. habitually.**
>
> For example:
>
> My grandparents claimed they would walk ten miles to get to school.
> When I worked as a mascot, kids would always be happy to see me.
> During her time as a food critic, she would visit many fancy
> restaurants.

[would versus will](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/will-vs-would/)

Comment: But , do we they mean the same or not?

Comment: No, of course they do not "mean" the same thing. Do these mean the same thing: I walk my dog every day. I walked my dog yesterday. One is in general and the other was yesterday. Same as in your question: One is present and the other is past. would is also used in conditional sentences, which is not the case here.||downvoter: tsk, tsk, tsk.

Comment: Oh please stop with the dv's. Provide your own answer.

Comment: @train bee 282 My dog will not let us catch him when he runs off. [a generality]. My dog would not let us catch him. [last night, when he **ran off**]. One time, specific.

Comment: No DV from me but I think the way the answer is formatted makes the examples less clear. Why is the example with **did** not emphasised?

Comment: You have enough rep to see deleted answers. Tell me what you think about the formatting and small tweaks I made.

Comment: Didn't let  means that it really happened wouldn't means what I think was possible to happen?

Comment: @trainbee282 Please see my edit to my answer. It is used as a determination: wouldn't let me=I have determined that about my dog.